Connection Between Shechem and Yitro? (and Amalek)
When Saul goes to war against Amalek, he tells the Kenites to withdraw from among the Amalekites (1 Samuel 15:6).
In Josephus's Antiquities, it is David who gives this warning when he is attacking the Amalekites who sacked Ziklag, however, "Shechemites" is used in place of Kenites.
Linking the two versions, is a one sentence mention of one of the Judges.

And Abdon the son of Hillel the Pirathonite died, and was buried in Pirathon, in the land of Ephraim, in the mountain of the Amalekites.

So Jethro's people are adjacent to the Amalekites and the verse from Judges confirms that there were Amalekites in the region of Ephraim, which contains Shechem.
Are there any Rabbinic sources confirming a connection between Jethro and Shechem?

I propose a edit, based on the content and tag of the question

David's battle with Amalek is noted in Tanach. This is evidently a different battle as compared to the Shaul's. http://sefaria.org/I_Samuel.30?lang=bi. At the time of David, Shechem belonged to Shevet Ephraim. There were no hivvim.

There were Jebusites in Jerusalem, why not Hivites in Shechem?
